# which assembly should i add to create Form in Vs-2012 using silverlight5

Tags: .net, forms, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0

I am new to c# silverlight . I am working in VS 2012 . I have to create form so that i would be able to edit the data.

I am beginner dont know how to start . I searched on google and found on a link that i need to include `System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm` which i couldnt find in VS on add refernce to my VS studio. I found a similar assembly called `System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.ToolKit.dll` . (on this link http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-Rich-Data-Forms-in-Silverlight-3-Introduction.aspx )
When i tried to do
include it in my xaml code  `<df:DataForm x:Name="myDataForm" />` then i found that it dont recognize `DataForm`.
How to do it any tutorial is also appreciated . Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're new to silverlight, then **STOP** silverlight in itself is no longer. It's better to focus on Windows 8.1 apps (and phone) or HTML 5 and Javascript or standard WPF.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&c2=12905

Comment: we have started working on project. Now its bit difficult to get a rid until we finish . Next time i will take care but do you have solution for my question ?

Comment: No I don't have it. I stopped Silverlight development quite some time ago. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a reference to the Silverlight toolkit assemblies in your project. You can grab it here from a link here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/0d4b20c0-aa13-456f-9227-ea5800bd0ed4/welcome-learning-resources-and-silverlight-toolkit?forum=silverlightcontrols

You will also need to add the required xmlns mappings in your xaml as described here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728664(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728664%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: @Ron thanks but it still dont answer me. I need to use create forms in a silverlight application where user can enter and edit some data. And i am not anle to find which assembly should i refer ? I am using silverlight-5.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to install Silverlight toolkit:
https://silverlight.codeplex.com/

after installing, you have data form in your toolbox list. Just drag and drop, and dependencies would be added automatically. If DataForm is not your toolbox, rightclick on toolbox, "choose items ...". then you can find DataForm there.

or you can do it manually

references:

`System.Windows.Data
System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input
System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit`

Xaml:

`xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"`

then you can have DataForm in your Xaml like:

`<toolkit:DataForm ...>`